# call to undefined method :: update_usage() error

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code segment where i get the monthly usage of ingredients used in production i don't know how i get this error `Message: Call to undefined method production_model::update_usage()` i want to manipulate the sum of `ingredient_qty` to use it on the equation `$ro = ((int)$total/(int)30) * (int)$lt;` am i doing it right?

```
//Gets Lead Time for reorder lvl

$this -> db -> join('purchase_orders', 'purchase_orders.order_reference = purchases.purchase_reference', 'left');
$this -> db -> join('suppliers', 'suppliers.supplier_id = purchases.supplier_id', 'left');
$this -> db -> join('products', 'products.product_id = purchase_orders.product_id', 'right');   


$this->db->select('suppliers.lead_time');
$this->db->from('purchases');

$this->db->where('purchase_orders.product_id', $rm);
$lt = $this->db->get()->row('suppliers.lead_time');  

//Gets monthly usage of raw mats
$this->db->join('production_batch', 'production_batch.pb_id = ingredients.pb_Id', 'left');
$this->db->join('production', 'production.batch_id = production_batch.batch_reference', 'right');
$this->db->where('ingredients.product_id', $rm);
$this->db->select_sum('ingredient_qty');
$this->db->group_by('month(date_produced)');

$q = $this->db->get('ingredients');

$total= $q->result();

$ro = ((int)$total/(int)30) * (int)$lt;

//Updates ReOrder Level 
$rou = array(
    'ro_lvl' => $ro,
);

$this->db->where('product_id', $rm);
$this->db->update('products', $rou);
```

this code segment is in the model

Answer (score 2):

It plainly states that there is no such function (in classes they are called methods) update_usage() insde of your model production_model.php.

Maybe you misspelled its name in method declaration  or just forgot to put into model file.

It has nothing to do with code itself.

Comment: i did not put such function on it, i'm thinking that parsing the value of `$total= $q->result();`  and using it to update the table triggers the error

Comment: Well, can you make sure that this is the reason? Try to debug script inserting exit; in different places. Also can you show entire code? It's not clear where this piece of code you provided comes from - model? controller?

Comment: this is in the model, i've updated it adding how i get the `$lt` from the equation. i know when you query a result from the database it returns it in an array but that's why i parsed it into an intger by `(int)$total`

Comment: Some code from elsewhere calls this function update_usage in production_model. The call may be in the model or in a controller. To find it you must determine - when does this error happen exactly?

Comment: that's exactly why i'm confused, never have i ever used a function called update_usage it triggers here `$this->db->where('product_id', $rm);
$this->db->update('products', $rou);` when i update

Comment: I'm positive that you've just overlooked this one. Check your controller, it is where you can find the method that is being called.